# Navbar collapse at 992 without dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I changed bootstrap's navbar collapse at 992px breakpoint but it still show me dropdown menu

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiRb5.png

using this standard css code

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    header nav.navbar-main.clearfix {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        background-color: white;
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

How can i do?

(I'm sorry for the external link but i dont have enought reputation to link an image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-main .navbar-nav li ul {
        display: block;
        position: inherit;
        left: auto;
        top: auto;
        width: 100%;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 0 0 0 10px;
        z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The first method is to generate a custom bootstrap in overiding the
  [breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints).
  *( I think it's the best way because it does the whole job alone )*
- The second method is too add this css lines to your given code :

  ```
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
      position: static;
      float: none;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header, .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
      padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
      line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
      color: #777;
  }
  ```

You can find a fiddle with a default navbar [here](http://www.bootply.com/4jemS1abY2)